# Windows UIAutomation "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" when application ends?

Tags: winapi, com, ui-automation, ole, microsoft-ui-automation

In a smaller test program using UIAuotmation and `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED)` I have no problems running in x64 debug mode in VS2017.   On a larger MFC app (x64 debug) that uses `AfxOleInit()` I get the **The object invoked has disconnected from its clients** when exiting the app if the UIAutomation object did something like call `IUIAutomation::ElementFromHandle()`.  Creating only the initial `IUIAutomation` object itself (i.e.  `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pClientUIA));` does not cause the issue.

I note the following as soon as the `IUIAutomation::ElementFromHandle()` method is called, the output window shows:

```
mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2125)\OLEAUT32.dll!00007FFB2155491B: (caller: 00007FFB21554A92) ReturnHr(2) tid(4cfc) 8002801D Library not registered.
'myapp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\UiaManager.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Later the `IUIAutomation` object "`m_pClientUIA`" (and anything else related to UIAutomation) is released without any issues.  Only once the app is terminating, you get two **exception thrown** dialogs with:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB1EDDA799 (KernelBase.dll) in myapp.exe: 0x80010108: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.
```

Any ideas on what is causing this and if it's anything I should worry about or just suppress?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any small reproducing project?

Comment: it's essentially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63063225/why-doesnt-ui-automation-condition-find-element-by-uia-isscrollpatternavailable - only need the findwindow part.

Comment: The code is not complete. The error may be due to what is not in the question's code.